# Mongo createUser command requires authentication

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, mongo-shell, createuser

I have installed Mongo 4.4 on Ubuntu 20. Im trying to create an admin user. But everytime I run the createUser command I get the following error.
[image]

How can I overcome this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

call: `db.auth("your username", "your password")`

Answer (score 0):

From the mongo.conf file, disable authorization under the security section.

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

Then restart mongodb using following command,

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Now, try to create your again. Do not forget to enable authorization back on after creating the user.